# Session State with Azure Redis Cache not working on multiple instances

Tags: asp.net, azure, redis

I'm using Azure Redis Cache to store the session of the users to share it over multiple instances.
But this not working... i'm logged in and as soon as the load balancer directs my request to the other Webserver i'm loggout out on the other server.
This is my current web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="RedisSessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="HOSTNAME.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="ACCESSKEY" ssl="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

In the portal i can see, that the application writes data into the cache so the connection is working.
If it is any help my authentication Part looks like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Welcome.aspx" defaultUrl="default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="60000" />
</authentication>
```

Is there anything else i need to do to get this running on multiple webservers?
In the tutorials i found only the configuration above regarding the sessionState.

Thanks for your help!

Br,
metabolic

Comment: of course i found the solution right after posting the quetsion here :). i had different machineKeys on the servers so the authentication cookie could not be decoded on the other Webserver... i did not find that information in any tutorial regarding Redis cache. but it seams to work now

Comment: Glad you found the solution.  If you could please close this question it would be great - helps people who want to answer questions focus their time on the ones that need attention.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem.
i had different machineKeys on the servers so the authentication cookie could not be decoded on the other Webserver.