# How to implement redis session provider in azure autoscalling environment in MVC 5 application?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, autoscaling, stackexchange.redis

1. What are the settings required to share the redis cache on all the available instances?
2. What changes required in the application for changing the session state provider?

Comment: Keep the same machine key on both servers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30448335/1273882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Install-Package Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider.

More description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider)